# Is there any lifecycle hook like window.onbeforeunload in Angular2?

Tags: angular, lifecycle

Is there any lifecycle hook like window.onbeforeunload in Angular2?
I already googled and searched on stackoverflow, but found nothing

Answer (score 94, accepted):

```ts
<div (window:beforeunload)="doSomething()"></div>
```

or

```ts
@Component({ 
  selector: 'xxx',
  host: {'window:beforeunload':'doSomething'}
  ..
)}
```

or

```ts
@Component({ 
  selector: 'xxx',
  ..
)}
class MyComponent {
  @HostListener('window:beforeunload')
  doSomething() {
  }
}
```

This is how to listen to global events. I don't know if the special behavior of this event is supported where the return value is used as text for the conformation dialog.

You can still use

```ts
export class AppComponent {  
  constructor() {
    window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
      return 'Dialog text here.';
    };
  }
}
```

Like explained here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Comment: What about the `window.onbeforeunload` approach? How does it not work?

Comment: Unfortunatelly, all 3 options dont work.
Does it have to be on the parent component? On the child component, it doesnt fire the event.   Example :  window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
        alert('Event triggered!');}

Comment: I updated my question. The code (last variant) shows the dialog when I navigate away from the page in Chrome.

Comment: How would I go about only showing the dialogue if some property of the component is true?

Comment: @oddRaven check out my answer below

Comment: Chrome no longer supports custom strings: https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5349061406228480

Comment: In Angular 4, the top solution with <div> worked for me. In my case I wanted to perform a user logout if the window or all tabs were closed.

Comment: The HostListener didn't work for me (it always prompted me irregardless of whether the page had changes) and the only thing I found to get this to work was using router-outlet. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51145053/2525272.

Comment: How could you test if this even works? AKA, if I navigate away from the page to make window.unload fire, how do I know my function ran? Console.logs wont work bc the app is destroyed. You guys mentioned a dialogue text, but I'm not sure if or where that would be read..

Comment: Sorry, don't remember. I only investigated it for this question back then and haven't used it myself anywhere since.

Comment: @KyleVassella Maybe a year late, but you can activate 'preserve log' option in the console and then it won't remove the log statements.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Awesome, I used step 3 and it worked perfectly fine. Thank you

Comment: Not works version 10

Comment: Works only if you have interacted at least once with the web page (like clicked some button or entered something on the page). Otherwise it will never stop on this listener.

Answer (score 73):

Günter Zöchbauer's answer is slightly wrong on <s>two</s> one count, this is what worked for me:

```js
@Component({ 
  selector: 'xxx',
  ..
)}
class MyComponent {
  @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  doSomething($event) {
    if(this.hasChanges) $event.returnValue='Your data will be lost!';
  }
}
```

There are two main differences from Günter's answer:

1. <s>The argument to `@HostListener` should be `window:beforeunload` and not `window:onbeforeunload`</s>
2. The handler shouldn't return the message, but should assign it into `$event.returnValue` instead

Comment: This code works for me. Unfortunately, this does not execute in my android phone when I close the tab. Any suggestions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35779372/window-onbeforeunload-doesnt-trigger-on-android-chrome-alt-solution might help

Comment: a dialog shows when the `returnValue` is anything but `null`. And most broswers dispaly a generic message to the user now. So you are not able to change it.

Comment: [returnValue is supposed to be a boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/returnValue)

Comment: October 2018 update, Angular 6: Needed to set `$event.returnValue=true;`. Any other value didn't work (false, null, string etc.).

Comment: @Marty131 so you set `$event.returnValue` to `true` and return the actual string message?

Comment: @Marty131 the update you mentioned is wrong - if not in theory then in practice - check out this stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ug2rgv

Comment: @AviadP. - If I attempt to close the StackBlitz tab you linked, it closes without any prompt. I am using Chrome on Windows 10. If I modify returnValue = true, then it will prompt me when closing tab/window. What browser and OS is it working for you?

Comment: Returning a string works for me in Chrome: `@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event']) handleUnload(e) { e.preventDefault(); e.returnValue = 'Wait!';}`

Comment: What is this.hasChanges here

Comment: error TS2339: Property 'hasChanges' does not exist on type component.ts

Comment: `hasChanges` is a property you should implement to return `true` if the view is 'dirty'

Comment: there is any way to add `if` to this argument? something like that `$event.returnValue = !!this.numberOfRequests;`

Comment: Works only if you have interacted at least once with the web page (like clicked some button or entered something on the page). Otherwise it will never stop on this listener.

Comment: Is there any way to find out if the page is being refreshed or closed?  I want to execute my script Tab/browser being closed.

Answer (score 14):

This worked for me. Defined in the page component constructor

```js
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", (event) => {
   event.preventDefault();
   event.returnValue = "Unsaved modifications";
   return event;
});
```

Define the `returnValue` only if you want to prompt user before unload.

Work only if the user interract with the page (e.g. click).

Comment: **Work only if the user interract with the page (e.g. click).** I kept refreshing the page thinking it does not work

Comment: Used this in my service where I need to make sure that critical section managed by localStorage is reopened when tab acquires lock and is closed at the same time (e.g. `localStorage.removeItem()`)

Comment: Thanks Nicolas, thanks Umutesen. Nicolas' function works perfectly, but you have to realize what Umutesen says; it only works if the user interacts with the page. (Which is actually PERFECTO)

Answer (score 8):

Important note for [iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127621/is-there-any-way-to-use-window-onbeforeunload-on-mobile-safari-for-ios-devices)

The `beforeunload` event isn't supposed - presumably due to the high level of 'abuse'
 over the years.

Instead you can use [pagehide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pagehide_event) as recommended by [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html).

This is part of the `Page visibility` API.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API

So I can't seem to get `pagehide` to fire on desktop chrome, and I can't get `beforeunload` to fire on iOS Safari - so you need both - but make sure not to fire your code twice.

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload')
@HostListener('window:pagehide')
```

Comment: On desktop chrome it works perfectly:

`@HostListener('window:pagehide', ['$event'])
  onClose($event) {
    console.log('hello')
  }
`

So you don't need to use both

Answer (score 4):

In angular we can create something like this.

```js
@HostListener('window:beforeunload')
confirmLeavingPageBeforeSaving(): boolean {
  // if 0 display dialog
  // if 1 you can reload
  return !this.myBoolean; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is more of an added note than an answer but I can't really comment right now.
Still, I wanted to add this:

I wouldn't say it's too complicated of initialization logic, but if you do decide to add the event listener on component initialization it would be best to include this in ngOnInit rather than the constructor:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.returnValue = '...';
});
```

This is especially if you are including additional logic before unload.

There's also a good article on [ngOnDestroy](https://wesleygrimes.com/angular/2019/03/29/making-upgrades-to-angular-ngondestroy.html) which works similarly to a destructor for directives, pipes, and services.  Both approaches are convenient depending on what operations you wish to perform.

Full link text: 
https://wesleygrimes.com/angular/2019/03/29/making-upgrades-to-angular-ngondestroy.html

*credit to Günter Zöchbauer's original answer*

Answer (score 1):

If one is looking for how to **add** and **remove** the listener.

```
 ngOnInit(){
  /*
   * Ask user if they are sure they want to refresh
    * -> Works only if the user interacts with the page (e.g. click).
  */
   window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.promptIfSureToRedirect, false);
 }

promptIfSureToRedirect(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.returnValue = 'Changes you made may not be saved.';
    return event;
}


 ngOnDestroy(){
   window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.promptIfSureToRedirect, false);
 }
```

In a component, listen to the event "beforeunload", then pass a function that will be called before unload.
On Destroy, remove this listener by passing the same function used to listen.

// -> I would like to big up @Nicolas and @Umutesen for the pointers

**Other pointers:**

-> Be sure to work with the event listener in the "window" element, don't interchange with document; e.g  `document.addEventListener`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the chrome documentation here: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/page-lifecycle-api/#the-beforeunload-event most of the answers here are ill advised for it prevents browsers from caching the page in their Back-Forward Cache.

The listener should be conditionally added and removed depending on whether some changes need to be saved or not. An example is provided in the link as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
You just need to add **beforeunload** in the component, Initialize when its require or in ngOnInit and at last, add remove even listener so its not effect pages of the application.
   
 @Component({
      host: { 'window:beforeunload': '' },
    })
    
    ngOnInit(){
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.checkLoad, false);
    }
    
    checkLoad(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.returnValue =
          'Are you sure you want to discard the form? Your process will be lost.';
        return event;
      }
    
    ngOnDestroy(){
        window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', this.promptIfSureToRedirect, false);
```