# Is there any other (prettier) way to prevent browser from reloading when a form is dirty?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-components

I want to build a Web Application which has a `form` that it's shared in multiple tabs. The functionality I want to implement is to prevent the user from reloading the page when the `form` is `dirty`. I tried [CanDeactivate Guard](https://angular.io/guide/router#candeactivate-handling-unsaved-changes), but it's useful only when the user navigates away. So, I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42986842/onbeforeunload-confirm-dialog-not-showing-when-angular2-hostlistener-is-used) implementation like this:

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event']) onBeforeUnload(event) {

    if (this.parentForm.dirty) {
      this.parentForm.form.markAsPristine();
      this.parentForm.form.markAsUntouched();
      return false;
    }

}
```

With this in place, I managed to prevent the user to reload, but the browser message is ugly:
[image: Browser Message]

Is there another way to accomplish the functionality I want with a more beautiful way?

Comment: If you are using reactive forms you can try something like this `this.parentForm.markAsPristine();
this.parentForm.markAsUntouched();`

Comment: @BogdanB Thanks for your answer! That was helpful. But generally, what I meant was that I want to implement all this logic in another way (e.g. by displaying a modal) and not by showing an ugly browser message.

Comment: Depends on your navigation event, if you are navigating inside your app you can leverage the [CanDeactivateGuard](https://angular.io/guide/router#candeactivate-handling-unsaved-changes). For navigation outside of your app (e.g. browser close, navigate to other pages) there is no better way.

Comment: @DanielHabenicht That was what I was afraid of. :/  Anyway, thanks for your answers.