# How to call back end service to force save before unload event in angular 7

Tags: angular

I want to save some data before unload the browser. but i want to do that after conformation if they press reload button means i want to save something, if they press stay here means want to stay same page. how to do this in angular 7.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your question is answered [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36763141/is-there-any-lifecycle-hook-like-window-onbeforeunload-in-angular2/39205395) where the `@HostListener` is used to listen for the `window:beforeunload` event which receives a callback before the window unloads.

The version I used from the provided post is as follows

```
@Component({ 
  selector: 'my-selector'
)}
class MyComponent {
  @HostListener('window:beforeunload')
  beforeUnload() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

All credit goes to [Günter Zöchbauer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36763141/is-there-any-lifecycle-hook-like-window-onbeforeunload-in-angular2/39205395)