# Call api before page refresh angular

Tags: angular

I want to call api before user navigates to url using href or reloading the current page. Here's my code that i have used.

```
@HostListener('window:unload', ['$event'])
 unloadHandler(event) {
 console.log('window:unload');
 this.storeSessionVistorsCount();
}

storeSessionVistorsCount() {
    if (this.sessionTime > 0) {
      const body = {
        ip: this.ipAddress,
        space_id: this.spaceId,
        type: 'session',
        time: this.sessionTime
      };
      this.statisticService.getIpDetail(body).subscribe((res: any) => {
        console.log('success')
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    }
  }
```

Api is cancelled by the browser. Can anyone help me out . Thanks.

[image]

Comment: where is `sessionTime`? and can you explain more - *Api is cancelled by the browser.*

Comment: did u try chaning :unload to :beforeunload ? you can also try canDeactivate hook - nice article to read https://medium.com/better-programming/angular-how-keep-user-from-lost-his-data-by-accidentally-leaving-the-page-before-submit-4eeb74420f0d

Comment: check [resolvers](https://codeburst.io/understanding-resolvers-in-angular-736e9db71267) in angular

Comment: Yes i tried using beforeunload also but browser cancels api call.

Comment: @PrashantPimpale That is just any number we can assume.

Answer (score 1):

You can call functions on specific lifecycle hooks in Angular. So like when the user leaves the application with a hard link `<a href="...">...</a>` or refresh you can take the `onDestory()` hook

```
@Component({selector: 'my-cmp', template: `...`})
class MyComponent implements OnDestroy {
  ngOnDestroy() {
    // Make your api call
  }
}
```

Here you can get additional information about life cycle hooks in the offical documentation: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Comment: It does not detect ngOnDestroy on hard reload or from href tag.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36763141/is-there-any-lifecycle-hook-like-window-onbeforeunload-in-angular2

Answer (score 0):

You can use a resolver in router to resolve data before the component loads.

Read more at: https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve

Comment: I dont want before component loads i want it on hard reload or clicking on href tag.

Comment: well only your index.html would run on a hard reload. So you could add a script in there if you want.

Comment: But i want some api to call where i can track time of visitor where he / she has visited in one page. Lets say tracking session.