# How to find F5 pressed and page is reloaded in Angular 6

Tags: angular, refresh, page-refresh

I would like to find if the browser is refreshed in app.component with out using router navigation . How to achieve this functionality

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window.onbeforeunload`.

```
window.onbeforeunload=()=>{
    this.myFunc();  // here you can do something like creating alert
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div (window:beforeunload)="doSomething()"></div>
```

See this post:
[Is there any lifecycle hook like window.onbeforeunload in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36763141/is-there-any-lifecycle-hook-like-window-onbeforeunload-in-angular2)