# Event is Deprecated Angular before Unload event

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to restrict the user to navigate to any link if there are any unsaved changes left, it works fine for most of the cases except two:

1. When user clicked the Log Out
2. When user clicked on a toggle button which is on layout level.

I tried to restrict the event by using Event but it is showing it as deprecated.

`

```js
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])

  canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> | boolean {

    if(*some condition*)
    {
      if(event)
      {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
      }
    }
      return *some condition*;

  }
```

`

I just wanted to stop the further propagation of the request

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any lifecycle hook like window.onbeforeunload in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36763141/is-there-any-lifecycle-hook-like-window-onbeforeunload-in-angular2)

Comment: I tried this but it still not able to solve my problem. @AdrianKokot

Answer (score 0):

When you are using event, you are using the deprecated `window.event` variable.

You can see its documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event) (and also why it is deprecated)

Your problem is that you want to use the event passed as an argument to the `canDeactivate` method, this method actually don't have any parameter (even if you declared in in your HostListener)

So all you have to do is pass add the event in the parameters of the method

```
 canDeactivate(event: BeforeUnloadEvent): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
```

That way you will use the event from the method parameter, not the window object

Comment: I tried this way but in this scenario the event is coming as undefined.

Comment: It works for me. https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-11-playground-forked-qftsjv?file=/src/app/app.component.ts:544-549 (open the console and try to refresh the page)

Comment: Yes, it worked for most of the cases like if you reload of navigate to any link but it is failing in only one case where it interacted with event like checkbox or button. Please try with checkbox. @Florent M