# What is a foolproof alternative to $(window).unload()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was reading jQuery documentation for the function `.unload()` given in the [jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/unload/)

It is written clearly that `.unload()` will is deprecated in versions after 1.8 and removed completely in 3.x.

I have a local intranet application that is dependent upon this `.unload()` function.

Do I have to manually rely on `window.onbeforeunload` function and see that a particular browser supports this or not, or can anyone help me in finding a more generic solution for the same.

As suggested by Kevin, I tried

```js
$(window).on("unload", function(e){
    return confirm("Do you really want to exit");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
Testing JQuery Unload in 3.x Version
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vibs2006/bqge8x22/)

But it is not working

Comment: replace `.unload()` with `.on('unload', function())` which is not deprecated.

Comment: _It is written clearly that unload function will not be depreciated in future versions after 1.8_ because it is already deprecated in 1.8 there are nothing left to deprecate after 1.8. Use the `on` method , which is the jQuery alternative of `adddEventListener` as suggested by Kevin

Comment: @KevinKloet as per you I have used **.on** method now. 

Can u help me in finding out that why my fiddle is not working https://jsfiddle.net/vibs2006/bqge8x22/

Comment: @SagarV my same comment (previous to this comment) question to you too. Pl guide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`unload` is a shorthand method in jQuery and is deprecated. When using `on`, you have to use the exact same event as present in JavaScript removing `on`.

Here, use `beforeunload` instead of `unload`

```js
//$(window).on("unload", function(e){
//              ^^^
$(window).on("beforeunload", function(e) {
//            ^^^
  return confirm("Do you really want to exit");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
Testing JQuery Unload in 3.x Version
```

Comment: @vibs2006, It does work in Firefox. The user just has to have interacted with the page appropriately in order for Firefox to permit you to have the user confirm leaving. You should [read the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload). Firefox is blocking your use of `confirm`, under some conditions, but the `onbeforeunload` event fires. Note that Firefox also does not permit a custom message in the confirmation to leave the page. You need to demonstrate a case where `$(window).unload()` works, but `$(window).on('beforeunload')` doesn't.

Comment: @vibs2006 Try the difference on Firefox in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wm1tu9qv/) between having not typed anything into the text area and after you type something into the text area.

Comment: Thanks @Sagar. Firefox now seems to be working fine.

Comment: Not working in Android phone Chrome browser

Comment: @MeenakshiKhandelwal https://stackoverflow.com/q/35779372/2427065

Comment: @SagarV I used `window.onunload = window.onbeforeunload` but did not work in Android Chrome.. other browsers are fine even in IOS Chrome is also fine.